# On Windows git can't handle files with the same name but in different case properly

Tags: windows, git

I use git on windows. In my project I changed case of filename. After that checkout of previous commits failed (commands are in Git Bash):

```
mkdir repofolder
cd repofolder
git init # create empty repo
git config core.ignorecase false # turn on case-dependent filenames

# create 'readme.txt'
$ echo "blahblahblah" > readme.txt
$ git add readme.txt
$ git commit -m "+readme.txt"

# rename it to 'README.txt'
$ git mv -f readme.txt README.txt
$ git commit -m "readme.txt => README.txt"

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git checkout HEAD~1
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by     checkout:
        readme.txt
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Why git doesn't allow to checkout previos commits?

You face with the same problem when delete one file and append another one with the same name, but different case. No matter how many commits you do: one (removing and appending in the same commit) or two commits (in first commit you remove file, in second you add another one).

Comment: Why are you turning off `core.ignorecase`?  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: "turn on case-dependent filenames" does so only for `git`. Your underlying file system in Windows is not case sensitive, and changing `git`s configuration will not fix that.

Comment: The solution is, of course, to not have files only distinguished by their case in the first place.

Comment: This problem does not have any sensible solutiuon because NTFS is case-preserving but case-insensitive so even while Git would be technically able to know what *exact* name a file has on the file system it wouldn't be able to somehow create side by side two files whole names differ only in case. A workaround is to checkout your repository on a system with a POSIX filesystem (any GNU/Linux-based OS would do), fix the capitalization issue, commit, tag and work cross-platform from there.

Comment: @kostix, technically, [NTFS supports several POSIX features including case-sensitive file names](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976809.aspx). The problem is that Windows itself and Win32 software access the filesystem in non-POSIX mode, effectively negating the feature. See below for details.

Comment: The root of the problem is that I have **only one file in commit**. I'm not trying to have two files with the same name but in different case. P.S. I set `core.ignorecase` to `false` because my project is built in Linux also.

Comment: @MaximSuslov, `git config` only applies to your current machine. Setting `core.ignorecase` to `false` because your "project is built in Linux also" doesn't make much sense. In any case, this is a distraction that doesn't have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: @Chris, (sorry for the long delay) I'm afraid no sane piece of Windows software is going to use the POSIX personality of Windows: apparently it has been created for a very specific pragmatic reason which has nothing to do with software portability -- Jeremy Allison of SAMBA [makes this very clear](https://www.samba.org/samba/news/articles/low_point/tale_two_stds_os2.html). In addition to what that article says, these days the game had changed, and I think it's sort of safe to completely ignore the existence of that POSIX layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On Windows git can't handle files with the same name but in different case properly

Git on Windows can't handle it because [*Windows itself* can't handle it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100625) (emphasis mine):

> As part of the requirements for POSIX compliance, the Windows NT File System (NTFS) provides a case-sensitive file and directory naming convention. **Even though NTFS and the POSIX subsystem each handle case-sensitivity well, 16-bit Windows-based, MS-DOS-based, OS/2-based, and Win32-based applications do not.**

In truth, Windows does have some level of support for NTFS case-sensitivity, but it's pretty flaky:

> However, if you attempt to open one of these files in a Win32 application, such as Notepad, you would only have access to one of the files, regardless of the case of the filename you type in the Open File dialog box.
>
> Other inconsistencies also exist. The Windows NT Command Prompt and File Manager correctly display the names of the files. However, normal commands, such as COPY, fail when you attempt to access one or more filenames that differ only in case.

Comment: The root of the problem is that I have only **one file in commit**. I'm not trying to have two files with the same name but in different case. So it doesn't matter that NTFS can't keep two files with the same name but in different case in the same folder.

Comment: @MaximSuslov, it doesn't matter whether you have "only one file in [the] commit". Windows doesn't distinguish between `readme.txt` and `README.txt`. When you try to check out your old commit Git tries to replace one with the other and Windows doesn't understand. This is the underlying cause of your problem.

Comment: But `git reset --hard HEAD~1` works fine! Why does `git checkout HEAD~1` fail?

Comment: @MaximSuslov, I don't know why `reset --hard` works. It's probably something to do with the implementation of the two commands. But Windows' inability to distinguish between files whose names are the same aside from case is the root cause, and you're going to continue to have trouble with this if you keep working on Windows.