# RA layer request failed: REPORT request on '/Development.XXXXXXX/!svn/me' failed at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 312

Tags: git, svn

We have a large SVN repository having almost 40000 revisions when we are trying to migrate that to git we are getting the above error.

The command we used is:

```
git svn clone <<SVN URL>>
```

Can any one help us here if you have faced it earlier.

Is it something to do with OS on which we are doing this migration?
Because I saw somewhere that they are able to do migration successfully in Unix based systems but facing this issue only in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it something to do with os on which we are doing this migration because I saw somewhere that they are able to do migration successfully in Unix based systems but facing this issue only in windows.

That would be the first test to do: try the migration from a Linux session (even from Windows, [using WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install))

That way, you can check if this is a Windows-specific issue (like a [file path length limit](https://serverfault.com/a/9548/783), or [Diacritic characters in filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55008118/6309))